# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 for a C sharp project. While running the project I am getting the following error in the browser

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource, Version=1.1.24.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can any one please provide me the solution

Comment: can you check the version of assembly in your o/p directory post build process

Comment: your bin/debug or bin/release..

Comment: its o/p directory

Comment: try to update the nuget package in Package Manager Update-Package Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource -Version 1.1.24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue and noticed that my project does not use `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource`, but uses `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist` and I just updated this reference to version 1.1.28 and it works

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist">
  <Version>1.1.28</Version>
</PackageReference>
```